# wrong permission with carrierwave (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, permissions, carrierwave

I ve a website where user can upload picture. Most of time, everything is working well, but from time to time, the file get wrong permission, 600 instead of default 644, and i can't find out why. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the required permissions to the carrierwave config file `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.permissions = 0644
  config.directory_permissions = 0700
  config.storage = :file
end
```

This and other information can be found on their [Github page](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-To:-Secure-Upload).

Comment: thanks for answer. But 0644 is permission by default anyway. And this still doesnt explain me why sometimes the file get 600 instead

Comment: so I was doing how you said, but I still have same problem, I dont understand what is wrong . Can it be linked with ubuntu ?